# Determine whether the terms of the functional are convex or strictly convex

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Suppouse $F(u) = \int^1_0 ((u')^2+3u^4+cosh(u)+(x^3-x)(u))dx \:in\: C^1[0,1]$. Where $u(0)=u(1)=0$

Consider the functional term by term. Decide for each term whether it is convex or strictly convex in $C^1[0,1]$. Let $u_0,u_1 \in C^1[0,1] ,\lambda \in [0,1]$.

For $\int_0^1 (u')^2dx$, since it is easily shown that $u_0' \ne u_1'$, $((1-\lambda)u_0' + \lambda u_1')^2 \lt (1-\lambda)u_0'^2 + \lambda u_1'^2$.

For  $\int_0^1 3u^4 dx$, since $3x^4$ is a strictly convex function, $3((1-\lambda)u_0 + \lambda u_1)^4 \lt 3(1-\lambda)u_0^4 + 3\lambda u_1^4$

For $\int^1_0 cosh(u)dx $, since cosh(x) is a strictly convex function $cosh((1-\lambda)u_0 + \lambda u_1) \lt (1-\lambda)cosh(u_0) + \lambda cosh(u_1)$

For $ \int^1_0 (x^3-x)(u)dx$ since this is just linear, $\int^1_0 (x^3-x)(1-\lambda)u_0 + \lambda u_1)dx = (1-\lambda)\int^1_0 (x^3-x)u_0dx + \lambda \int^1_0 (x^3-x) u_1dx$

Feedback would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: It seems all right. Just as na exercise, you could try to calculate the second derivative and show it is positive definite.